# Update UIlabel text with a String

Tags: arrays, swift, uilabel

I have a label in the prototype table view cell, and also a `UITextviewfield`, I want to update the text of the label by using `UITextviewfield`.

first I created a struct:

```
struct CellElements {
   let title: UILabel
}
```

then an array:

```
var list = [CellElements] ()
```

then I use these codes to add the text inside the `UITextfield`to the list array and later I will add them in the table view.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var inputField: UITextField!
 @IBAction func addName(_ sender: UIButton) {
    list.append(inputField.text)
}
```

the problem is, swift doesn't let me to do that with this error

```
Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type 'CellElements'
```

I will appreciate for your help in advance.

Comment: What is UITextviewfield?

Answer (score 3):

`list` is an array of `CellElements`. When you attempt to append to that array, you need to add a `CellElements` instance.

But your line:

```
list.append(inputField.text)
```

is attempting to append a `String`. Hence the error since `String` isn't `CellElements`.

What you want to do is to create an instance of `CellElements` from the text field and then append that instance.

```
list.append(CellElements(title: inputField.text!))
```

Note that you need a `String` and `inputField.text` is an optional `String`. This is a case where you can safely force-unwrap an optional. See the documentation for `UITextField text` for why this is safe.